# How many satellites are actually used to get position?

Tags: gps, nmea

[NMEA 0183 Version 4.10](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/u-blox8-M8_ReceiverDescrProtSpec_%28UBX-13003221%29.pdf) defines that there cannot be more than 12 satellites in GGA message:

> Number of satellites used (range: 0-12)

But there can be more active satellites defined in GSA:

> satellites used for navigation, and DOP values

So how many satellites are actually used to calculate position?

See example:

> $GNGGA,155000,4700,N,03201.46451,E,1,**12**,0.78,9.5,M,27.7,M,,*4E
>
> $GNGSA,A,3,**21,18,20,16,10,15,27,08,32**,,,,1.27,0.78,1.01*11
>
> $GNGSA,A,3, **68,83,76,69,85**,,,,,,,,1.27,0.78,1.01*11

12 satellites in GGA

14 (9+5) satellites in GSA

Comment: I would imagine that this would partially depend on how many channels your GPS has. There is also the PDOP at any given point in time and space.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer:

> When the NMEA standard was created many years ago no one was expecting
>   anyone could use more than 12 satellites for resolving location
>   because the number of satellites visible at once was less than that,
>   thus the GAA message was limited to 12 SVs. Now with our fancy
>   multi-constellation receivers it’s very common to have a lot more than
>   12 SVs but those receivers have to be backwards compatible with older
>   NMEA versions (currently 4.11) thus they limit the GAA SVs field to 12
>   but in the newer GNS field it can go up to 99.

https://github.com/mikalhart/TinyGPSPlus/issues/52